# What are the common words for 'Horizontal' and 'Vertical'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider these expressions:

> Don't place the [suitcase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suitcase) **vertically**, it will mess up all of the clothes inside. Keep it **horizontally** on the floor.
>
> I keep the books [vertically](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=vertical+books+in+sheld&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=3Yp-Ud6EF4G2rgG4yoDYCQ&biw=1594&bih=808&sei=PIt-UYvQAtGGqQG8vIGgDQ#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&q=vertical+books+in+shelf&spell=1&sa=X&ei=pot-UanML5TpqAHD4oDwBA&ved=0CFAQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.aWM&fp=f02d9cc28d2ddeeb&biw=1594&bih=808&imgrc=3PARwh3Gr-h-HM%3A%3BZtReRtWnvnJSRM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmedias.photodeck.com%252F67c32562-0890-11e0-9ddc-499fc09cac18%252F1071_1247332_xlarge.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.spacesimages.com%252Fmedia%252F67c32562-0890-11e0-9ddc-499fc09cac18-old-books-on-a-bookshelf%3B400%3B600) in my shelf unlike this [arrangement](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=horizontal+book+shelf&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=74p-Uf3MGIrQrQHD-YDYBw&biw=1594&bih=768&sei=9Yp-UeraDcrErgGWpIC4CQ#imgrc=1jO99SQNRjYI_M%3A%3BHCGzgrmtURBGHM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252F3.bp.blogspot.com%252F_-4BHTNnMJ2E%252FTUsnbOtlniI%252FAAAAAAAAAzI%252FSvCFXCXXScM%252Fs1600%252Fbook%25252Bhorizontal%25252Bdisplay_studio%25252Bparade_paperback.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fawdesignlog.blogspot.com%252F2011%252F02%252Ftop-shelf.html%3B1600%3B1200).

The words **horizontally** and **vertically** sound very technical to me. I use them in physics or maths but I rarely see them in movies or books.

Is this the natural way of describing these arrangements?

Comment: They're not very technical, and sometimes are the best to use.  Most people will understand what they mean, since [horizon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/horizon) is sort of related.

Comment: Side note, one of your examples sounds odd:  If I used "horizontal", I'd say either `Keep it horizontal on the floor.` or `Lay it horizontally on the floor.` - the "-ly" implies some sort of action being taken.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would perhaps say:

> Don't keep the suitcase **upright**, **lay it flat** on the floor.
>
> **Stand** the books **up**, don't **lay them flat**.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on the context.

If you're talking about placing an elongated object, than I agree with FakeDIY that we would say "lay it flat" or "stand it upright".

If you're talking about a direction of movement, we normally say "left and right" or "up and down", as in, "Turn this knob to move the light up and down. Push this lever to move it left and right."

There are probably other words in different contexts.

Comment: I agree. My answer only really applies to this specific context.